# Create request with SOAP ui

Tags: testing, soap, automated-tests, soapui

Is it possible to create soap ui request with data ? right now I know how to create new request which gives you template what you should send to your webservice (which is read from you wsdl), is there a way so your requests fills with data based on type(ex: String,Integer, Date) from wsdl, from soap ui or any other test tool ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter data directly into the XML request generated by SoapUI, you can write scripts to populate data, or if you have the Pro version, it gives you a GUI form, based on the request, where you can simply type the data. i.e. it makes a data-entry screen for you.
The pro version can also pull data from databases, generate data from a string list, etc.. for example, I recently needed to send several thousand SOAP payloads with dummy data for firstname/lastname, etc.. So I made up two string lists, one with first names of past and present NFL quaterbacks, one with last names.  I had the data generator in SoapUI (Pro) randomly select a string from each, and submitted it in a stress test for 1000 iterations. The results were very useful, yet very amusing, giving names like Drew Montana.

Answer (score 8):

In Soap UI 4.5.1 there's an option under preferences that once set will auto populate new requests with dummy data that is type safe instead of the default '?'.

File->Preferences->WSDL Settings-> Tick option "Sample Values" and hit OK.

Comment: This! Thank you, you saved me a ton of time! Donating virtual cookies!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use SOAPUI to complete this task. you can fetch your data from several sources like Excel,plain csv file,Database liks DB2,POSTGRES. You can also write your groovy scripts to control the flow.Various things you can do to achieve this...